# Display all results from a ManyToMany Query

Tags: php, mysql, many-to-many

My mind has completely gone blank on this one but I currently have a manytomany relationship setup and I am trying to figure out how to print the data back on the php end. I know I can call the the following command to display the results in phpmyadmin:

```
SELECT skills. * 
FROM `skills_matches` skills_matches 
LEFT JOIN `skills` ON skills.id = skills_matches.skillid 
LEFT JOIN `users` ON users.id = skills_matches.userid 
WHERE skills_matches.userid =70 LIMIT 0 , 30
```

and then I have I the following function to call that query:

```
function fetchAllUserSkills($id)
{
    global $mysqli,$db_table_prefix; 
    $stmt = $mysqli->prepare('SELECT skills . * '
        . ' FROM `skills_matches` skills_matches'
        . ' LEFT JOIN `skills` ON skills.id = skills_matches.skillid'
        . ' LEFT JOIN `users` ON users.id = skills_matches.userid'
        . ' WHERE skills_matches.userid = ?'
        . ' LIMIT 0 , 30');
        $stmt->bind_param("s", $id);

    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->bind_result($id, $skills);
    while ($stmt->fetch()){
        $row = array('id' => $id, 'skills' => $skills);
    }
    $stmt->close();
    return ($row);
}
```

But, when I try the following statements, the results turn out blank:

```
$skillDetails = fetchAllUserSkills(70);
echo $skillDetails['skill'];
echo $skillDetails;
```

I did a `var_dump` on $skillDetails and got the following:

```
array(2) { ["id"]=> int(15) ["skills"]=> string(5) "sales" }
```

So the question is: What am I missing in order to display all the results from that query in php like I did in phpmyadmin?

Comment: Note that LIMIT without ORDER BY is silly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are overwriting $row each time:

```
$row = array('id' => $id, 'skills' => $skills);
```

should be

```
$row[] = array('id' => $id, 'skills' => $skills);
```

Then to display, you would loop over the returned data:

```
$skillDetails = fetchAllUserSkills(70);
foreach($skillDetails as $row) {
    echo $row['skills'];
}
```